# MBProgressHUD can not show

Tags: ios

I am using `MBProgressHUD` to show user a tip, but it is not showing. There are many `viewcontrollers` that use the same method. Only one page can not show it, this view controller is created with xib.
the method is following:

```
-(void)creatHUD:(NSString *)hud {

    if (!HUD) {
        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view] ;
        [self.view addSubview:HUD];
        HUD.delegate = self;
    }
    HUD.labelText = hud;
}
```

Comment: Can you put some code of method you are using to show progress MBProgressHUD.

Comment: Will you Please add code for this viewcontrollers which MBProgressHUD not working.

Comment: are you presenting hud from viewdidload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
UIView *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

MBProgressHUD * hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window animated:YES];

[hud show:YES];
```

hope this will work...

Comment: -(void)creatHUD:(NSString *)hud{
    if (!HUD) {
        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view] ;
        [self.view addSubview:HUD];
        HUD.delegate = self;
    }
    HUD.labelText = hud;
}

Comment: can you tell me why the method can not work?i really suspect it is relative to  the xib.

Comment: I think the problem is that your adding hud in self.view instead of window try to add hud in window in your method.

Comment: I have added hud in window in my method and it works as soon as i saw your answer yesterday.But i still doubt that why the method above can not work well.as you know ,in the other view controller,the method work well.

Comment: hey you are missing [HUD show:YES] this line of code try it.

Comment: You give a good remind,but I have found the reason of the problem.It is the time when the method should be used that  i missed .I use the method in the func of viewdidLoad when the view is all load,but my method is used to add hud self.view ,so ,hud will not be shown

Answer (score 0):

since question is not clear, i think you are trying to show with background thread. please try this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //show Hud code here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use MBProgressHUD too, my implementation is:
1. Only show MBProgressHUD in `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow`
2. Never add more than one Hud into view.
I package it, here is my code:

```
#define APP [UIApplication sharedApplication]
+ (MBProgressHUD *)Hud
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:APP.keyWindow];
    if (hud){
        [hud removeFromSuperview];
    }else{
        hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:APP.keyWindow];
        hud.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;
    }
    [APP.keyWindow addSubview:hud];
    return hud;
}

+ (void)showMsg:(NSString *)message
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [self Hud];
    hud.labelText = message;
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
    hud.labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    [hud show:YES];
    [hud hide:YES afterDelay:1.0];
}

+ (void)showLoading
{
    [self showLoading:@"please wait..."];
}

+ (void)showLoading:(NSString *)message
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [self Hud];
    hud.labelText = message;
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    [hud show:YES];
}

+ (void)hideHUD
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:APP.keyWindow];
    [hud hide:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing in swift try this one

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

        MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!, animated: true)
    }
```